# Display image from URL stored in data from API

Tags: javascript, image, url, jsx

I am trying to add an image to a small weather app that I'm building. The image url is stored in the data of the API that I'm using but I'm can't figure out how to display this image.

I've attempted to simply post it with  but the url posts instead of the image and the code below is causing the app to crash.
  < img src={this.state.forecasts[0].icon} alt="Icon"/ >

[Errors popping up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhWKO.png)

[data stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhWKO.png)

Comment: Can you share the full code? What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!! 
instead of < img src={this.state.forecasts[0].icon} alt="Icon"/ > i needed to write   < img src ={this.state.forecasts ? this.state.forecasts[5].icon : "none" }/>